__builtin_clz returns wrong answer with valid inputs other than 0
So, on my M1 MacBook I'm writing a library (using Apple Clang), for which I need to count the number of leading (and trailing, but that seems to work just fine) zeroes of certain numbers.
I obviously went for the easy route and just used __builtin_clz for this, so that I didn't have to do any bit manipulation for this part of the project. Now, I found a bug and I traced it back to said function. A bit of testing revealed that for __builtin_clz of a uint8_t equal to 1 it returned 31. For uint16_t equal to 1 as well, and the same goes for uint32_t and uint64_t.
This struck me as odd, given that sizeof(uintN_t) always returned the expected value (of 1, 2, 4, and 8 respectively).
I'm compiling with -O3 and -march=native, which may be causing some problems, but since I'm running the programme solely on my own machine, the second one shouldn't be of any issue and the optimisation level should only possibly cause weird bugs when invoking UB, which I didn't do because I don't put 0 into the function, only valid arguments.
Is there any documentation I could consult regarding this issue? Does anyone have any suggestions where the problem may lie? I know I could just do a bit of bit masking myself, but that would defeat the whole purpose of the function and doesn't resolve this bug.
Thanks in advance!
P.S. of course I tested for values other than 1 – same bug :(

inline auto uint8_clz(uint8_t x) { return x ? __builtin_clz(x) - 24 : 8; }

Is there any documentation I could consult regarding this issue? yes https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fclz

btw note that "If x is 0, the result is undefined."

I assume you do something like this
uint8_t n = 1;
std::cout << __builtin_clz(n) << '\n';

So the correct result would be 31 because __builtin_clz receives an unsigned int as argument. Clang will convert your input to uint32_t before passing to the function. There's no bug at all. I'll be surprised if compilers produce the wrong result for such basic operations. There are __builtin_clzl and __builtin_clzll which receive unsigned long and unsigned long long respectively. There's also __builtin_clzg for generics but no version specifically for uint8_t
But don't use compiler-specific builtins. In C++ you should use std::countl_zero and std::countr_zero instead. It has an overload for unsigned char and doesn't have undefined behavior for zero so you just need
return std::countl_zero(n);

Whereas with __builtin_clz you'll need to specifically check for 0
return n == 0 ? 8 : __builtin_clz(n) - (sizeof(unsigned int) - 1)*CHAR_BIT;

In older C++ standards you can use boost::multiprecision::msb() which will automatically map to the compiler's intrinsic so performance is still great

Another possible older standard alternative is bitset<T>::count(), recent enough STL implementations would also use intrinsic.
